# Changing an integer in scrollTop to a div

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to wrap my head around this, but I'm having a hard time doing so. So I have this navigation that changes from one color to another color based off the `scrollTop` function. However I don't like that, and I want the navigation to react after getting past a certain div.

```
            $(function() {
              $(window).on("scroll", function() {
                if ($(window).scrollTop() > 550) {
                  $("nav").addClass("active");

                } else {
                  //remove the background property so it comes transparent again (defined in your css)
                  $("nav").removeClass("active");
                }
              });

              new WOW().init();
            });
```

How would I change `if ($(window).scrollTop() > 550) {` (the integer) from that to a div? So the div being `#video`.

I basically want the navigation to change colors AFTER the scroll reaches the div `video`.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well instead of comparing it to a hard 550, just compare it the location of your `#video`:

```
if ( $(window).scrollTop() > $('#video').position().top )
```

Comment: If `position()` doesn't do it, then use `offset()`.

Comment: It worked like a charm @American Slime thank you so much!!!! learned something new!